# Malformed <script> tag when using Microsoft XSL

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, xslt, msxsl

I have created an MVC web application that displays transformed XML files as views (the application is being used a web portal to view DITA-like documentation). I created a custom IView class called `XmlView` that takes into an XML file and a XSL stylesheet as parameters.

```
public class XmlView : IView {

    string xmlFile;
    string xsltFile;

    public XmlView(string xsltFile, string xmlFile) {
        this.xmlFile = xmlFile;
        this.xsltFile = xsltFile;
    }

    #region IView Members

    public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) {

        var xslSettings = new XsltSettings {
            EnableScript = false
        };

        var xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings {
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
        };

        var xslParams = new XsltArgumentList();
        xslParams.AddParam("applicationBasePath", "", UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl("~", viewContext.HttpContext));

        XmlReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = XmlTextReader.Create(xmlFile, settings);
            var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer, "\t");

            xsl.Load(xsltFile, xslSettings, null);
            xsl.Transform(reader, xslParams, htmlWriter);
        } finally {
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The transform file looks something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias result-prefix="#default" stylesheet-prefix="xhtml"/>

    <xsl:param name="applicationBasePath"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test Case <xsl:value-of select="/*/requirements/requirement/@id"/>
                </title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$applicationBasePath}Content/test-case.css" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="test-case">
                    <!-- Removed for brevity. -->
                </div>
                <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `XmlView` is fed an XSL transform that transforms the XML file into HTML and then outputs the resulting HTML. However, when I include an HTML <script> tag in the transform, the XSLT processor outputs malformed XML in which some of the closing tags of parent tags are nested within the <script>. For example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Test Case 1067</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="test-case">
            <!-- Removed for brevity. -->
        </div>
        <script></body></html></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've attempted to swap out the <script> for other tags (both self-closing and otherwise), and those tags do not cause a problem, only <script>. I've also attempted to build the tag using <xsl:element> to no avail. I've attempted to enclose the tag in a CDATA section, but that does not have desirable results.

My suspicion is that <msxsl:script> tag may be interfering but that hypothesis still leaves many things unexplained especially since I disabled scripts on the XSLT processor.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your XSLT creates XHTML output. Shouldn't your .NET code use `XhtmlTextWriter` istead of `HtmlTextWriter` if your aim is to output XHTML? Or make sure your XSLT creates HTML by removing the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`. XSLT 1.0 processors like `XslCompiledTransform` are not really suitable in creating XHTML to be served as text/html and parsed by HTML parsers.

Comment: I didn't know that there was also an `XhtmlTextWriter`. I changed that as well although it's more likely that the `xmlns` attribute in the stylesheet was the culprit.

Comment: To make it clear, if you change the stylesheet to output HTML without namespaces then you should continue to use the `HtmlTextWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the default namespace declaration from the stylesheet and consequently from the <html> tag in the output XHTML did the trick.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml"
>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```